# Why I do not get the following message on running grails app "Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/qotd"?

Tags: grails, http-status-code-404

I am following the instructions in the chapter 1 in book "Grails in Action, second edition".

What is on my machine?
| Grails Version: 3.2.0
| Groovy Version: 2.4.7
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_101

Are GRAILS_HOME and JAVA_HOME configured?
YES

> /home/myName/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current/bin:/home/myName/software/jdk1.8.0_101//bin:/home/myName/bin:/home/myName/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

I follow the below given commands in terminal

> grails create-app qotd
>   cd qotd
>   grails run-app

The script runs and gives me the following message (message 1)

> Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development

however the expected message (message 2) after executing the script is;

> Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/qotd

The message 1 link is active while the message 2 link gives me following message on the server.

### Page Not Found

```
Error: Page Not Found (404)
Path: /qotd
```

yes, I tried the solution where they ask to add following code in application.yml file
server:
    'context-path': '/qotd'

the result of implementing that solution is given below

> Grails application running at message 1/qotd in environment: development.

Further I am not able to click on the links created by controllers and the "view/controller_name" folders are empty (No index.gsp files created)

I get "SLF4J" warnings on executing the run-app command, however I do not think it will have anything related to the problem.

Comment: Does Grails in Action cover grails 3 or 2 ? `Grails 3` to `Grails 2` significant change there

Comment: @vahid The book covers grails 2 (very specific: Grails 2.3)

Comment: Well then `What is on my machine? | Grails Version: 3.2.0` stops there so far as why you are seeing `http://localhost:8080`  vs `http://localhost:8080/qotd` two very different technologies Grails 3 vs 2 http://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/guide/upgrading.html gives you an idea - Grails 3 is spring boot app

Comment: @vahid that answered my question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

try changing the following

```
server:
    'context-path': '/qotd'
```

to this in your application.yml

```
server:
    contextPath: '/qotd'
```

Do not add quotes around contextPath.

Comment: I did it too but it didn't work for me because I have grails 3 on my machine and I was following the instructions from the book "Grails in Action, Second Edition" which is based on grails 2

Comment: @Anjant you can move over to grails 3 when you have worked through the Grails in Action book with grails 2. Install old GGTS or maybe even STS to be able to follow instructions and do as they say. There are some real differences even between 2.3 and 2.4 of grails. For example from resources to assets in 2.3 to 2.4 which is the underlying functionality of CSS/JS files. I started with 2.1 and worked up to 2.4 and got into 3 quite easily but cos I was using it as it progressed.